# Working with wordpress using laravel valet, unable to increase maximum upload limit

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-valet

Wordpress keeps stating max file upload limit is 2mb. phpinfo() says the same. Using PHP ver 7+

Have tried changing by creating php.ini and .htaccess files in both root and wp-admin directories. Nothing seems to work.

php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

Answer (score 7):

Open a terminal and type

```
$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.1
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-geoip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-redis.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

Open php-memory-limits.ini like that :

```
nano /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

You can now update the file with other value for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Save it and valet restart.

Comment: This worked for me, I've added `phpinfo();` to one of my Valet sites to understand which version of php is being used. Openened the `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini` file and edited the upload and memory values. Ran `valet restart` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you edited the php.ini file that is referenced in your phpinfo() and that you restart the services using `valet restart` afterwards.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may help you

A) Theme Functions File

There are cases where we have seen that just by adding the following code in the theme function’s file, you can increase the upload size:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );

@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');

@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

B) Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file

In most cases if you are on a shared host, you will not see a php.ini file in your directory. If you do not see one, then create a file called php.ini and upload it in the root folder. In that file add the following code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M

post_max_size = 64M

max_execution_time = 300
```

C) `htaccess` Method

Some people have tried using the `htaccess` method where by modifying the `.htaccess` file in the root directory, you can increase the maximum upload size in WordPress. Open or create the `.htaccess` file in the root folder and add the following code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

php_value post_max_size 64M

php_value max_execution_time 300

php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Hi @shibu-vs. It looks like the content of this answer is copied directly from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/. Can you edit your post to reflect proper attribution. Plagiarism is not welcome on stack overflow. (Ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)

Answer (score 1):

I don't if this is your case,

BUT

if you are working with a Wordpress Network (multisite) , be aware that there is a network setting for this in `/wp-admin/network/settings.php`

I spent an hour on this *%#@£%!

Comment: Omg... I did the same thing. The limit was set in my multisite uploads settings xD Thought I was going mad....